# Remote audio amp turn on, using multi triggers via diodes

Tags: diodes, audio, automotive

Pretty sure this is sane but would like other eyes on it.

Problem: Add an amplifier to a vehicle with multiple sources (head unit and hi-res bluetooth streamer). System is powered by house batteries (sprinter van). I want to trigger the amplifier remote-on from many sources, such as ignition, switch in rear, on signal from BT streamer that it is streaming.

Approach: Use +12vdc signals via a Schottky diode, to let any one of the three sources trigger powering on the amp. here's what I mean (sorry for the ASCII art!)

```
Ignition   -----|>|-----------\
Trigger #2 -----|>|------------------    REMOTE input on amplifier 
Trigger #3 -----|>|-----------/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your overall plan is reasonable.  You are constructing a diode OR gate.

Provided that your remote-on is triggered by a roughly 12 V signal, and your sources won't be negatively affected by the (small) reverse leakage of Schottky diodes, this setup should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

That is fine, if any source is on then the remote input terminal will get voltage. The diodes will block current if a source is on and others are off.

Make sure the diodes are rated for the current that the remote input might take. Also make sure that if the current is in the amps range there won't be a problem with thermal dissipation/temperature or that the heat dissipated by the part won't be more than what the part can handle

Comment: Thx. Yes, the REMOTE IN is a very low current draw signal, as in <50ma. The 1000W amp power is on another 2awg wire.